# why doesn't FireBug highlight breakpoint line?

Tags: firebug, highlight, break, breakpoints

Using FireBug 1.7.3.  It won't highlight the source line of breakpoints or errors, making them difficult to find.  If I press F10 to step to the next line, I can see it, but I may want to do an F11 instead, or check a value before stepping one more statement.
[image: FireBug is not highlighting the source line on breakpoint or error]

Sorry about the image, it's my first time uploading.  The line in question is 476, in the middle of the code on the left; the "debugger;" statement all alone.

Comment: Is that still an issue for you using Firefox 20.0.1 and Firebug 1.11.2?